# Create bitmap image from camera buffer in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, windows, bitmap, uwp, intptr

I am trying to create a new UWP C# BitmapSource image from an unmanaged memory buffer (IntPtr) from a USB camera.  The code below works fine in Windows 8, and I successfully ported it to WPF, but now I need to collect these raw images from the camera using Windows 10 UWP (latest Fall Creators Update is fine) and UWP does not support **BitmapSource.Create**. Any help would be great porting this to UWP and watching out for memory leaks with unmanaged code with clean dispose. Thanks!

Working code on Windows 8 .Net 4.6.2:

```
    private Bitmap CreateBitmap(int width, int height, IntPtr image)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        var palette = bmp.Palette;
        for (var i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
            palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
        }
        bmp.Palette = palette;
        var bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        try
        {
            Win32.CopyMemory(bmd.Scan0, image, (IntPtr)(bmd.Stride * bmd.Height));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.Log.Instance.Error($"Bitmap create: {e.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Working code on WPF .Net 4.6.2:

```
    [System.Security.SecurityCriticalAttribute]
    private BitmapSource CreateBitmapSource(int width, int height, IntPtr image)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pf = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed8;
        int rawStride = (width * pf.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
        int bufferSize = rawStride * height;
        BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed8, BitmapPalettes.Gray256, image, bufferSize, rawStride);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: `BitmapSource.Create()` does more or less exactly what you already have in your first code snippet, which sets up a `Bitmap` object and copies the raw data into it (accepting that you make a few assumptions about the layout of the raw input data).  Is there any particular reason that you don't want to use the first (manual) approach if the framework `BitmapSource.Create` isn't available?

Comment: UWP does not support Bitmap so must support BitmapSource (correct?) also trying to avoid Win32.CopyMemory as I understand this is slow and not very portable+dangerous, but not sure about this advice.  Is there any  UWP "native" support for importing IntPtr bytes to an image?  What is the best way for quality/speed/no memory leaks in UWP?

Comment: Can you look into and try the code in this topic [Create, edit, and save bitmap images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging)?